# Split .sql Backup File

Tags: mysql, ssh

I download backup of my database every week from my hosting. It generates a .sql file that currently has approximately 800mb. This .sql file contains 44 tables.

**Is there any way, through some software that I can split the .sql file with all the tables, in order to individually export each table?**

So, if I had to reset the backup at some point, I would do it by table, and I would not have to do to the entire database.

Comment: Yes use something like MySQL Workbench. That allows you to pick one or some tables out of a dump file to be restored. And best of all IT FREE

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's an alternative. But for my pretty case, i prefer the solution of @Delano zuurman . BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't split it after, if you have server access yourself over ssh you could (and in my eyes should) do something like this :

```
for table in `mysql -u [USER] -p[PASSWORD] -N -B -e 'show tables from [DATABASE]'`;
do
    mysqldump --skip-comments --compact -u [USER] -p[PASSWORD] [DATABASE] $table  > $table.sql 
    && tar -czvf $table.tar.gz $table && rm $table.sql
done;
```

Which should generate one file per table. Then just .gz whatever directory you put the files in and you should have your backup in the way you want it.

Comment: 1) "for table in `mysql -u [my_user] -p [my_pw] -N -B -e 'show tables from [my_db]'`; do mysqldump --skip-comments --compact -u [my_user] -p [my_pw] [my_db] $table  > $table.sql done;" 2) "Enter password: my_pw" 3) "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '[my_user]'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" !! What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, it seems like you are using a user that isn't allowed to access, have you tried to verify the username/password combination?

Comment: Yes, i'm using PuTTY . The password have 15char, but i tried many times. And always occurs the Error 1045(28000) . What can i do throught the console of the Phpmyadmin? Can i apply this kind of instrutions or similar ?

Comment: try it like you did but after the -p don't enter the password, it will then prompt you for the password and you can fill it in. See what happens (might be strange signs or something in your password).

Comment: Same. i try a easy password like "aaaaa" just for test, and returns a same error "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '[my_user]'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" . May a problem from PuTTY ?

Comment: can you login with the same credentials with : Mysql -u[username] -p

Comment: Ok my friend. Removed the password after the "-p" but now, the prompt ask me a password 44 times (for each table); Theres no way to compat the db to .gz instead save in .sql?;

Comment: If you can enter the password and it works now, that would mean you are doing something wrong in the script or i wrote something wrong. So does the password work now ? For example did you use a space between -p and the password ? if so remove the space. or try : -p'yourpassword'

Comment: Now is all work how you suggest. TY;
Theres some way to compress this to .rar (or other) without export directly to .sql ; Just because it spend a lot of space in my 1GB host . And i've 800MB already occupied . If i made a DB backup directly on cPanel, whole DB is compressed in 80MB (.rar), uncompressed it goes to 700MB (.sql); Question: Can i made this compression (somehow) to each table with your SSH script?;

Comment: I've added that for you, it should compress every table now, if you want to compress the directory you put them all in just put the tar command after the done;

Comment: experience: "mysqldump --compact -u my_user -pmy_password my_db $table  > .aaa-ssh-db-backup/$table.sql tar -czvf $table.tar.gz $table";
result; "mysqldump: unknown option '-z'" (44 times, for each table)

Comment: Updated needed to separate the commands so the tar only runs after the dump. Try again please.

Comment: With your update returns: "tar: EACH_TABLE: Cannot stat: No such file or directory;tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors;"; And duplicate on the output directory for each table 1x .sql file, and 1x .gz file; If it's possible i just need a .gz file for each table, the .sql can be excluded once exists inside the .gz file .

Comment: ah i see try this : tar -czvf $table.tar.gz $table.sql

Comment: I'm using like this: "mysqldump --skip-comments --compact -u my_user -pmy_password my_db $table  > folder_backup/$table.sql && tar -czvf folder_backup/$table.tar.gz folder_backup/$table.sql"; But in my 'folder_backup' it duplicates each table in one .sql file and one .gz file; I just pretend one .gz file for each table;

Comment: Have a look at my latest edit. Just use rm to remove the sql file after comrpessing it.

Comment: Dear @Delano zuurman 100% solved ! This is it ... Thank you very much for your patience. You help me a lot.